# Applying Conditional Formatting Row By Row based on Cell Critieria

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

Struggling with this one. Have a table  with many columns but looking to apply the conditional formatting to a subset.  Table looks like below. Number/name of columns are fixed but number of rows varies based on some user inputs. Below image shows the table

[Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmW0z.png)

With this table I am looking to apply the color scale conditional formatting on a row by row basis. The added wrinkle is the formatting needs to be dependent on the value in the column titled "Sign". Logic goes if Sign value in row is "+" then applies color scale with green for highest value, red for lowest and white for 50th percentile (used macro recorder to capture stock color scales in excel to produce code below). If Sign value in row is "-" then I reverse it with Red for highest value, green for lowest.

My code is as per below. Problem I'm facing is it is duplicating the formatting for each row MANY times and slowing down everything. Any ideas why its duplicating the formatting for each row?

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

```
Dim Rng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim i As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each Rng In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1[[Sign]:[TREND5]]").Rows
    For Each cel In Rng.Cells
    For i = 1 To Len(cel)
    
If cel.Value = "+" Then

Rng.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
    Rng.FormatConditions(Rng.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
        xlConditionValueLowestValue
    With Rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
        .Color = 7039480
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = _
        xlConditionValuePercentile
    Rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
    With Rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
        .Color = 16776444
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = _
        xlConditionValueHighestValue
    With Rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
        .Color = 8109667
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    
ElseIf cel.Value = "-" Then

Rng.FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3
    Rng.FormatConditions(Rng.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    Rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = _
        xlConditionValueLowestValue
    With Rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor
        .Color = 8109667
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = _
        xlConditionValuePercentile
    Rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 50
    With Rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor
        .Color = 16776444
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = _
        xlConditionValueHighestValue
    With Rng.FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor
        .Color = 7039480
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

End If

Next i
Next
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `If rng.Cells(1) = "+" Then` and `ElseIf If rng.Cells(1) = "-" without the `For Each...` and the `For i...` and the `Next i` and a `Next`?